# Why do strange data come to the server and browser console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I send Ajax query on server and output data in browser console

```
let price = $(this).attr('data-price');
let name = $(this).attr('data-name');
//Push data in items
items = [{
            price: price,
            name: name
        }];
console.log(items)

$.ajax({
    url: '/url'
    method: 'post',
    data: items
})
```

Response in browser:

```
items:[{
   price: 90,
   name: 'TWIX'
}]
```

Response on server:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  'items[0][price]': "'90'",
  'items[0][name]': "'TWIX'",
}
```

What to do?

Server code:

router.js

```
router.post('/url', UserController.newData)
```

UserController.js

```
const newData = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body)
    } catch (e) {
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            message: `${e}`
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: Arrays are actually objects that has index as keys, I think the output is correct. Unless you are facing any issue

Comment: @T.J.Crowder added server code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not convert items to json

Need:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/url'
        method: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(items)
    })
```

Server:

```
let test = JSON.parse(req.body.items)
console.log(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the data as JSON, are you using some kind of middleware on the node server to parse it properly?

I assume you are using Express

You'll need to use something like body parser and add

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

before the controller registeration. And this should probably fix this.